# How can I get data from HTML and then calculate it and print it out using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I was assigned do the job of a grocery store, and get data from html about the customer, what they buy in what quantity, and their price. With the click of a button, it's supposed to display the information, along with the calculated cost and sales tax of the person (like a check). I am not able to do this, and cannot find my mistake.
Code:

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  var customerName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var fruitName = document.getElementById("fruits");
  var i = fruitName.selectedIndex;
  var itemName = fruitName.options[i].text;
  var itemQuantity = document.getElementById("qty").value;
  var unitPrice = document.getElementById("unitPrice").value;
  var tax = document.getElementById("tax");
  var l = tax.selectedIndex;
  var salesTaxRate = tax.options[l].value;
  var output = "";
  var total = parseFloat(unitPrice) * parseFloat(Quantity)
  var salesTax = parseInt(salesTaxRate) * total
  var grandTotal = salesTax + total
  document.write('Customer Name: ', customerName)
  document.write( < br / > )
  document.write('Item Name: ', fruitName)
  document.write( < br / > )
  document.write('Quantity: ', itemQuantity)
  document.write( < br / > )
  document.write('Unit Price: ', unitPrice)
  document.write( < br / > )
  document.write(total)
  document.write( < br / > )
  document.write(salesTax)
  document.write( < br / > )
  document.write(grandTotal)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Unit 2 Assignment</title>
</head>

<body>
  Customer Name:
  <input type="text" id="name" /><br /> Item Name
  <select id="fruits">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select><br/> Quantity
  <input type="text" id="qty" /><br /> Unit Price
  <input id="unitPrice" type="number">
  <br /> Sales Tax
  <select id="tax">
    <option value="0.025">2.5%</option>
    <option value="0.05">5%</option>
    <option value="0.08">8%</option>
    <option value="0.10">10%</option>
    <option value="0.60">60%</option>
    <option value="1">100%</option>
    <option value="2">200%</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <button id="calculateButton" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Calculate Total</button><br />
  <p id="output">
  </p>

  <script type="application/javascript" src="assignment_2.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`

Comment: You never added anything to `output`, what are you expecting `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;` to do?

Comment: You need to put string arguments to `document.write()` in quotes.

Comment: Like `document.write('<br/>')`

Comment: @Barmar thanks for helping, what do you mean by adding something to output? Sorry again I'm very knew to JS and a beginner programmer in general i've been doing JS for less than a week

Comment: Thank me later ;) [JavaScript Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the help

Comment: You do `var output = "";` and then `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;`. If you intended this to display something that you calculated, you need to put that result into the `output` variable.

Comment: You can just use `tax.value`, you don't need to get the value of the selected index.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the help, I still don't really understand why the function isn't writing anything when the button is clicked though. Could you also maybe post working code? It would help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the output you want to display in the `output` variable, not use `document.write()`. You can use a template literal to simplify writing this.

You had a few incorrect variables in your calculations and output: `Quantity` should be `itemQuantity`, and `fruitName` should be `itemName`.

When calculating the tax, you need to use `parseFloat(salesTaxRate)`.

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  var customerName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var fruitName = document.getElementById("fruits");
  var i = fruitName.selectedIndex;
  var itemName = fruitName.options[i].text;
  var itemQuantity = document.getElementById("qty").value;
  var unitPrice = document.getElementById("unitPrice").value;
  var tax = document.getElementById("tax");
  var salesTaxRate = tax.value;
  var total = parseFloat(unitPrice) * parseFloat(itemQuantity)
  var salesTax = parseFloat(salesTaxRate) * total
  var grandTotal = salesTax + total
  var output = `Customer Name: ${customerName}<br>
Item Name: ${itemName}<br>
Quantity: ${itemQuantity}<br>
Unit Price: ${unitPrice}<br>
${total}<br>
${salesTax}<br>
${grandTotal}`
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Unit 2 Assignment</title>
</head>

<body>
  Customer Name:
  <input type="text" id="name" /><br /> Item Name
  <select id="fruits">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select><br/> Quantity
  <input type="text" id="qty" /><br /> Unit Price
  <input id="unitPrice" type="number">
  <br /> Sales Tax
  <select id="tax">
    <option value="0.025">2.5%</option>
    <option value="0.05">5%</option>
    <option value="0.08">8%</option>
    <option value="0.10">10%</option>
    <option value="0.60">60%</option>
    <option value="1">100%</option>
    <option value="2">200%</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <button id="calculateButton" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Calculate Total</button><br />
  <p id="output">
  </p>

  <script type="application/javascript" src="assignment_2.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```